# Azure Data Transformation Logic

Tags: azure, data-transform

Is there no way to add an additional column at the Sink and create a dynamic expression? This will be a derived column whose value depends on some joins from source tables.

I have tried using data flows but data flows is unable to directly utilize source sql server columns for transformation logic in sink without utilizing a blob storage. Creating blob storage is out of scope for us.

Comment: What is the sink? What value you need to add there?

Comment: @Aswin   The sink is azure sql database table. i need to dynamically populate value for column on basis of a query select c. A, p. B as StrNum from A C inner join C. CID = A. CID inner join (2 more tables on primary column) inorder to populate column StrNum

Comment: If you want to get the column from the query, you can click the **Query** option in `use query`.  The columns in the query can be copied to the sink database.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional column in **copy activity** itself instead of using **data flow activity**.

- In Source tab of copy activity, you can add additional columns.
- Click **+New** in the additional columns section.
- Enter the Name of the column in Name text box.
- Give the type of column expression in value and enter the value of that column.

[image]
img1: Source settings in copy activity.